# Apply map on pandas column only if the key exisits

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to this in python

```
df_svn_subset['job_title_name'] = df_svn_subset['job_title_name'].map(alias_job_titles)
```

I noticed that when I am checking the existence of null values in the job_title_name column that it goes up after applying the latter above. Therefore, how can I apply the latter above only if the key exists otherwise just ignore?

Answer (score 1):

update with the job_title_name, when map returns null using fillna

```
df_svn_subset['job_title_name'] = (df_svn_subset['job_title_name'].map(alias_job_titles)
                                   .fillna(df_svn_subset['job_title_name']))
```

Comment: Does this actually skip the value if they key does not exist in that map?

Comment: @Wolfy, this will create a series that has NaN for the missing keys, then replace those with the corresponding values from the original series. One downside of this method is that it will convert an integer series to float if there are any missing values, unless you add `.astype(df_svn_subset['job_title_name'])` to the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper function instead of the dictionary itself, like this:

```
df_svn_subset['job_title_name'] = df_svn_subset['job_title_name'].map(lambda x: alias_job_titles.get(x, x))
```

This will try to lookup the value of each cell (`x`) in the dictionary, and if it's missing, it will use the current value of `x` instead.